# agora.io Error Access denied finding property net.dns2

Tags: java, android, agora.io

Am trying to implement a live streaming app using `agora.io`, on test vision. When i click on start streaming I get error below and camera will be blank.

```
W/GENP.0: type=1400 audit(0.0:74945): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:net_dns_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=3282 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:net_dns_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
E/libc: Access denied finding property "net.dns1"
E/libc: Access denied finding property "net.dns2"
    Access denied finding property "net.dns3"
E/libc: Access denied finding property "net.dns4"
```

Please any idea what is causing the issue.

Comment: Are you testing on the emulators, which could cause this error? Meanwhile, this error should not cause any performance issue of the SDK.

Comment: No am testing it on a real device, I didn't make any changes on the example code from GitHub, just added my `app_id` and `token`

Comment: After copying your token and pasting it to the String.xml file, please double check if the token is actually used when joining the channel.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After a long research I found out that why the live isn't starting and the screen is blank was because i created a token in agora dashboard with a `channel name` `test1`, but in my app while opening live I passed the `channel name` with user id.

So in other to make agora work you need to create a token with same channel name which you will pass while starting live.

But this fix still didn't stop the error `Access denied finding property "net.dns1"` in log, but now I can go live.

Comment: Here worked in physical device, but in emulator didnt work.

Comment: @Peter I'm trying to find out that where I can pass channel name https://github.com/AgoraIOUsecase/AgoraVoice/blob/master/AgoraVoice_Android/app/src/main/java/io/agora/agoravoice/business/server/retrofit/interfaces/RoomService.java               Kindly help me with this. This project uses a rte-1.1.0.jar (https://github.com/AgoraIO-Usecase/AgoraVoice/tree/master/AgoraVoice_Android/app/libs) file which I couldn't find in the documentation